# MooTools: destroy() and events

Tags: javascript, mootools

When I `.destroy()` an `Element` object in MooTools, does .`destroy()` automatically internally call `element.removeEvents()`, or do I need to keep this in mind. (I'm removing elements from the DOM that have previously had `element.addEvent()` called.)

Answer (score 3):

**.destroy()** in MooTools, version 1.2.4:

```
destroy: function(){
    Element.empty(this);
    Element.dispose(this);
    clean(this, true);
    return null;
}
```

The **clean(item, retain)** function does `.removeEvents()` if the browser needs it:

```
var clean = function(item, retain){
    ....
    if (item.clearAttributes){
        var clone = retain && item.cloneNode(false);
        item.clearAttributes();
        if (clone) item.mergeAttributes(clone);
    } else if (item.removeEvents){          
    ....
};
```

You should be safe, it's emptying out the elements.

Also, credit for all code above to MooTools of course:  http://mootools.net/

Comment: Not if the browser supports it, but if the `item` sent to the `clean()` function does. `removeEvents()` is a Mootools function itself, not a builtin function.

Comment: @Håvard S - Actually I trimmed some logic out, it's wrapped in a `if (Browser.Engine.trident){` as well, basically an IE check...other browsers already remove events properly, this is an IE only memory leak band-aid.  I changed the above "supports" to "needs"...hopefully a clearer answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Mootools will call `removeEvents()` when you call `destroy()` on an element.

(The current implementation does this in a function called `clean()` that is called from `destroy()`).